# Explaining a memory static heap allocation

Tags: c

```
void Heap_Init(void){ int i;
int32_t *pt;
  pt = FreePt = &Heap[0];
  for(i=1; i<NUM; i++){
    *pt = (long)(pt+SIZE);// the first word of a free block points to another free block
    pt = pt + SIZE;       // value of pointer pt should increase by 4*SIZE
  }
  *(long*)pt = NULL;      // the last free block points to NULL
}
```

I'm trying to understand that line:

```
*pt = (long)(pt+SIZE);// the first word of a free block points to another free block
```

How would assigning a value *p of a pointer to next pt + size work ?
would someone visualize it to me please ?

```
#define SIZE 4  // number of 32-bit words in each block
#define NUM 5   // number of blocks
#define NULL 0  // definition of empty pointer
int32_t *FreePt;   // points to the first free block
int32_t Heap[SIZE*NUM];
```

How that function works too?

```
void Heap_Release(int32_t *pt){
int32_t *oldFreePt;
  oldFreePt = FreePt;
  FreePt = pt;            // newly freed block is first
  *pt = (int32_t)oldFreePt;  // newly freed block points to previous first
}
```

Comment: What is `Heap`? Where is that defined?

Comment: @tadman added and modified the post

Comment: That's not a very big heap. Not sure how you'd allocate or release from something so tiny.